# How can a UICollectionViewDatasource inform the UICollectionView about changes?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am tinkering around with a CollectionView that displays items from a changing data-model. I have a class that represents my data-model as UICollectionViewDatasource.

In my data-model it happens that items get replaced by other items. These replacements are not triggered by any user interaction they are a result of a computation in the background.

I am trying to figure out how my DataSource can inform the view that an item has changed and that the view needs to refresh.

I can't find a way how the datasource would inform the view of any changes in the datamodel - as the view seems to query the datasource only?

Is the only way to keep a reference to the view and call reloadItems(at:) on the changing items in the view?

I am a bit worried that I am mixing datamodel and view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: insertItems(), removeItems(), reloadData(), reloadSections(), reloadItems()

any of which can be called when your data model changes to cause the view to call its delegate.